# Can Cas13 edit DNA

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

Can Cas13 be used to edit DNA or is it only for RNA?

I have tried looking at literature and my understanding is that it can only edit RNA.

Answer (score 2):

The Cas13 protein targets/edits RNA specifically and not DNA. That said, as you probably know, the Cas9 protein is famously used to edit DNA and was the inspiration that led the Zhang Lab to seek out the Cas13 protein for editing RNA.

If you're interested, you can [read here](https://zlab.bio/cas13) for some additional detail on how Cas13 targets RNA and why it's RNA-specific.

Comment: The question asks "Can Cas13 edit DNA" - why is your answer about Cas9?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clearly but I was just trying to make the point there *is* something that edits DNA, but it's not Cas13. Will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't start with "yes" :)

Comment: Done, yes was intended to reply to "is it only RNA" but you're right that that was not very clear :).

Answer (score 1):

No, Cas13 can't be used to edit DNA. Cas13 does not contain nuclease domains RuvC and HNH  domains responsible for DNA cleavage, so they cannot directly edit the genome. For that Cas9 and Cas12a is used.